# intersphinx undefined label warning

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

Following http://sphinx-doc.org/latest/ext/intersphinx.html I added `sphinx.ext.intersphinx` to the extensions in my `conf.py` and then I defined a mapping to Python 2.7 documentation:

```
intersphinx_mapping = {'python': ('http://docs.python.org/2.7', None)}
```

And I added this reference in my reST source:

```
:ref:`comparison manual <python:comparisons>`
```

I also downloaded https://docs.python.org/2.7/objects.inv which I decoded to reST, to confirm that comparisons label exists in objects.inv:

```
:std:label:comparisons:
    :Link:  :std:label:`python:comparisons`
    :Domain:    Python
    :Version:   2.7
    :URL:   reference/expressions.html#comparisons
    :Title: Comparisons
```

However, when I try to build my documentation I get this warning:

> WARNING: undefined label: python:comparisons (if the link has no
>   caption the label must precede a section header)

and I don't get any link in build html file.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Cannot reproduce. Using ``:ref:`comparison manual <python:comparisons>` `` works fine here.

Comment: I'm on Ubuntu 14.04 and using Sphinx '1.3.1'. It's good to hear that this indeed should work.